# I created two text boxes called username and password using html and i want to check the username and password matched or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function buttonclick(){
    if(document.getElementById("txt1").value==document.getElementById("txt2").value){
      alert("user name and password are matched");
    }
    else{
      alert("user name and password are not matched");
    }
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

`field.setCustomValidity("Invalid field.");` will make the field invalid.

```js
  function buttonclick(){
    if(document.getElementById("txt1").value==document.getElementById("txt2").value){
      alert("user name and password are matched");
      document.getElementById("txt2").setCustomValidity("Invalid field.");
    }
    else{
      alert("user name and password are not matched");
    }
  }
```

```html
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="txt1"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="Password" id="txt2"><br>

<button type="button" onclick="buttonclick()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the password" id="firstField"><br><br>
 <input type="text" placeholder="ReEnter the password to confirm" id="secondField"><br><br>
<button onclick="checkAction()">Submit</button>

<script>

function checkAction() {
    if(document.getElementById("firstField").value==document.getElementById("secondField").value) {
        alert("Pasword Mathced");
    } else {
        alert("Password donot matched");
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```